# Copy sheet paste as values but skip protected cells

Tags: vba, paste, protected, cells, skip

i am looping through several sheets and want to delete the ones i dont want. for the ones i want to keep i am copying the everything and pasting as values. the problem is that there are protected cells which i cannot uprotect and that gives me an error. how to avoid that?

```
Sub save()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim path As String
Dim fname As String
Dim fdate As Date

' picks up the date of the reporting period so it uses it for naming the new workbook
fdate = Sheets("Instructions").Range("D1").Value
Sheets("Introduction").Range("F9").Copy
Sheets("Introduction").Range("F9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Introduction").Range("F10").Copy
Sheets("Introduction").Range("F10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'FOR EACH SHEET IN THE WORKBOOK THAT IS ONE OF THE 5 ONES WE WANT TO SAVE IS COPIES AND PASTES AS VALUES AND DELETES THE ONES THAT ARE NOT NAMES AS BELOW
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sheet.Name = "Introduction" Or Sheet.Name = "Instructions" Or Sheet.Name = "Results" Then
        Sheet.Select
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Selection.Locked = True
        Sheet.Range("D2") = fdate

        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    Else
        'if sheet is not one of the X it gets deleted
        Sheet.Delete
    End If
Next

' adding the name we wish to give the new workbook
fname = Sheets("Introduction").Range("F7") & "Result" & fdate
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
'ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="password", Structure:=True, Windows:=False


'saves the workbook as the name we chose and date
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "\" & fname, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'close the workbook
ActiveWindow.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

and i have tried some code like:

```
for each cell in sheet 
   if Not cell.Locked then
     cell.copy
     cell.pastespecial xlpastevalues
   end if
next
```

but is not working, it gives me an error in the "for each cell in sheet" error 438 that the obect is not defined or something like that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: where have you tried to add this part of the code ? can you add your full code combined ?

Comment: that would be after the "if sheet.name...then". So i am looping each cell to the sheet and check if it is locked. or that is what i am trying to do but doesnt work.

Comment: hey, i any suggestions? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The declaration for cell is missing and next you need a range in the sheet to loop through (.UsedRange loops through all used cells in a worksheet). This should work:

```
Dim cell As Range
for each cell in sheet.UsedRange
   if Not cell.Locked then
     cell.copy
     cell.pastespecial xlpastevalues
   end if
next
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment and suggestion. It seems that it finds all the cells to be locked so it skips the copy paste which is strange as i can copy and paste it manually. Any suggestions?